# Android turn screen off while running tasks in background

Tags: android, camera, motion-detection

I have a requirement in android application where i want to turn off screen when no motion has been detected(Motion detection is done using camera).

But the camera should be running in background and taking pictures while the screen is off and as soon as the motion is detected then the screen should be turned on.

How can i do that in android?

I have searched a lot and implemented few things but could not achieve the desired result.

Please help me out.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is possible. To take a picture the `Camera` class needs the `SurfaceHolder` and it needs to draw the frame on the screen for the capture to work.

Comment: But i am taking the pictures without showing the preview i am using PictureCallback.

Comment: You mean you're taking pictures using some other way other than explained [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) under `To take pictures with this class, use the following steps`?

Comment: yes. I am not using preview. I am capturing image using front camera and that image is returned as byte array to class implementing PictureCallback.

Comment: OK so if that's implemented then you only have to deal with motion control. :) @Rajnikant 's answer should help.